# How to move subsite and Workflow to another site collection

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-server

I want to move subsite to a site collection with all the workflows (Nintex), their running status and history?

Can anyone let me know how this is possible. Is there any third party tool available to do this?

Comment: Have you tried Export-SPWeb? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428293(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: @Bunzab: As far as i know Export-SPWeb does not include workflows. This is the limitation with Export/Import.

Answer (score 2):

Their is no OOTB way to move a subsite to other locations with Workflow etc. In your sitution you can do:

- use third party tools and move it. There are couple which offer free trial may help you like Sharegate.
- I think, backup site collection and restore to other location and then delete the all unwanted stuff.
- also check this may be help u http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/how-to-copy-workflows-from-one-site-collection-to-another-with
- move the subsite, then manually move the workflow. The workflows must be exported from the old subsite via the Nintex Workflow Designer and then imported into the new subsite or site collection, again using the Nintex Workflow Designer.

Comment: third party tools may help me..but since it is a subsite and i also want to maintain the running status of workflow. So i guess tools are the only solution..Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: yes, thats the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are number of tools available in market like.

Metalogix
Sharegate
AvePoint

You can also migrate by Content Database attachment method.